# fstream input and output position are the same although inherited from istream and ostream

Tags: c++, stl

I want to to delete all data in binary files in the range: 10-19.

```
fstream myFile(f.bin, ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::app | ios_base::binary);
myFile.seekg(20);
myFile.seekp(10);
myFile << myFile;
myFile.close();
```

The problem is that internal position is stored in a single place.
Although here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/iostream/
it is stated that it inherited from different base classes, and should been stored twice.

I understand I can use 2 different streams. But I am asking how to achieve this with a single stream?

What about using intermediate stream which is not a file stream- to avoid reopening the file again?

Comment: Editing a binary file in-place seems like a bad idea. Why do you want to do that ? A bit more context would be appreciable, else it might be seen as an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/163733).

Comment: `myFile << myFile;`???? Wut???

Comment: That is exactly what I've asked. How to edit binary file in place without using 2 fstreams.

Comment: fstream won't be enough to resize a file in-place. It is just not possible, unless you are calling an operating-system dependant function (such as ftruncate) after the fact. It is much easier to read the file, write a temporary file omitting those bytes, delete the original file and rename the new file to have the original name.

Comment: What if I don't have enough space in memory, nor on HD?

Comment: then you'll have to read everything from 20 till EOF, iteratively, and write each 'block' 10 bytes before where it was read, and then 10 bytes will be duplicated at EOF and you'll have to ftruncate the file.

Comment: The STL streams cant help me with this?